# Different behavior of gettext between developer and real sites

Tags: php, gettext

Any help with the following bug with gettext is greatly appreciated!

I have an array of translated strings, and a function that can be called to get a specific translation

```
$names = array();
$names['new'] = _('New');
// etc...

function name($string)
{
    global $names;
    
    // this will work fine on my developer site using XAMPP
    return $names[$string];

    // but in the real site it won't work unless I do
    return _($names[$string]);
}
```

Why does it need to translate a second time before returning? Or better put: why didn't the first translation work when pushing the value to the array?

There's obviously nothing wrong with the value of $string, or the PO files, etc. as it does work the second way (translating before returning)

Can the problem be with PHP versions, or Linux vs Windows? Or because the array is global?

Comment: Instead of messing with the global, just pass $names as an argument to the function.

Comment: `Can the problem be with PHP versions, or Linux vs Windows`, sure, it is possible.

Comment: I don't see here any sign of `gettext` bugged behavior. Alias form `_($names[$string])` used in second return statement which is ok according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php). Probably, as you mentioned, issue is in the `global` keyword. When you are not sure, `Xdebug` is your best helper. Moreover, i would suggest to use `Dependency Injection` approach, and to have service that you can get from container instead of using `global`. Or centralized abstraction layer from which you can get translations. Your call.

Comment: Thank you Sergey and imvain2. But how would the use of a global variable cause the difference of behavior between the two sites?

Comment: Problem indirectly could be that you are reassigning the variable somewhere in the code and creating `scope` collision after making it global. Use `namespaces` instead to avoid collisions. But in your case its hard to give direct answer because you are showing only small portion of your solution. Moreover, in order to be more specific you need to describe both ENVs in details (no need to give some sensitive info) but at least to make it visually look like a bug report. Which is understandable for the community.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you don't need neither `name()` function nor `$names` global var. Simply use `echo _('New');` where needed. And don't forget `setlocale()` and `textdomain()` before first call to any gettext function.

Long answer: gettext is not about asking a programmer to use translation arrays and/or functions. gettext is about the idea that any text that is normally output in english, should simply be enclosed as a parameter to one of gettext functions. Here, `_()` is simply an alias to `gettext()`, but there are also functions for handling plural forms and context-aware variants. In any code that needs a translated output in place where you normally write `echo 'New';` you just write `echo _('New');`. All the rest is a process outside of code. And yes, you have to first initialize gettext by defining which language you are using for this specific request and from which file (domain file) you are loading the translations. The `_()` function looks up the specified domain file for the parameter (`'Name'` in your example) and returns corresponding translation from this domain file.

For more details see [GNU gettext manual on files](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Files.html).

I didn't see `setlocale()` nor `textdomain()` calls in your example, they are both required BEFORE the first call to `_()` (before the `$names` array initialization). There are good examples at [php manual on gettext](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php). So maybe the translation didn't work because the locale was not set or domain file not provided.

Translations are not done automatically. To prepare the domain file the source code is scanned and translatable lines are extracted. Then those lines need to be translated into target languages. Good news, this process can be accomplished either online or with a downloadable tools like [POedit](https://poedit.net/).

Back to your example, if `setlocale()` and `bindtextdomain()` calls are done before the provided call is executed and the translated domain file is in place, your `name()` function should work fine with the first return statement (if you decide to keep it at all).

It could also work in your dev environment if gettext used by default a system domain file from the OS, and it apparently had an entry for the `'New'` string. But this can only work for common strings on specific target OS for languages installed on this OS ;-) Not guaranteed that the same default catalogs and locales are installed on production server.